# What is the difference between Python 3.2 and 3.1?

Tags: python

newb coder here

I have decided to dive headfirst into python and discovered there are different versions of python such as Python 3.2, 3.1 etc. Could someone please tell me if there is any difference? if I learn an older version would i have to re-learn a newer version or is it just an update to the libraries and stuff? Sorry if it seems trivial, I'm new to this

Comment: This is something you can easily learn from a Google search, such as "difference between python versions"

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Python 3.2 release notes](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/3.2/) for specifics. You shouldn't notice any syntax differences or issues between 3.2 and 3.1, especially if you are just beginning. You shouldn't be worried about learning one then having to learn the other, they are basically the same.

Also, Python is very good about being backwards compatible, so almost everything you would do in 3.1 would work in 3.2

There are noticeable differences between Python 2.x and 3.x, where there are some changes in  syntax and the way things work. Even then, if you "learned" Python 2.7, you'd be able to figure out 3.2 in a matter of minutes once you understand the differences.